# ORACLE SQL how to link 2 tables twice

Tags: sql, oracle, apex, wms

I have 2 tables case_hdr and locn_hdr

On case_hdr I have columns locn_id and prev_locn_id
On locn_hdr I have locn_id and locn_brcd

I want to create report that will show me case_nbr adn locn_id and prev_locn_id but both locations to be displayed as locn_brcd??

Any suggestions please?

Comment: What is CASE_NBR? There's no reference to it in what you posted so far. Also, sample data and desired result would help, it is difficult (at least, to me) to guess what you want.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, just maybe, this is a case of changed and mixed IDs. It is imposible to tell, but if I'm  guessing it right this could help you get the picture.

```sql
WITH
    case_hdr AS
        (
            Select 1 "LOCN_ID", 101 "PREV_LOCN_ID" From Dual Union All
            Select 2 "LOCN_ID", 102 "PREV_LOCN_ID" From Dual Union All
            Select 3 "LOCN_ID", 103 "PREV_LOCN_ID" From Dual Union All
            Select 4 "LOCN_ID", 104 "PREV_LOCN_ID" From Dual Union All
            Select 5 "LOCN_ID", 105 "PREV_LOCN_ID" From Dual 
        ),
    locn_hdr AS
        (
            Select 1 "LOCN_ID", 11 "LOCN_BRCD" From Dual Union All
            Select 102 "LOCN_ID", 12 "LOCN_BRCD" From Dual Union All
            Select 3 "LOCN_ID", 13 "LOCN_BRCD" From Dual Union All
            Select 4 "LOCN_ID", 14 "LOCN_BRCD" From Dual Union All
            Select 105 "LOCN_ID", 15 "LOCN_BRCD" From Dual 
        )
Select
    ch.LOCN_ID "LOCN_ID",
    ch.PREV_LOCN_ID "PREV_LOCN_ID",
    lh.LOCN_ID "LOCN_ID_FROM_LOCN_HDR",
    CASE WHEN lh.LOCN_ID = ch.LOCN_ID THEN 1 ELSE 2 END "CASE_NBR",
    CASE WHEN lh.LOCN_ID = ch.LOCN_ID THEN 'Linked by ID' ELSE 'Linked by previous ID' END "CASE_NOTE",
    CASE WHEN lh.LOCN_ID = ch.LOCN_ID THEN ch.LOCN_ID ELSE ch.PREV_LOCN_ID END "LOCN_BRCD",
    lh.LOCN_BRCD "LOCN_BRCD_FROM_LOCN_HDR"
From
    case_hdr ch
Inner Join
    locn_hdr lh ON(lh.LOCN_ID = ch.LOCN_ID OR lh.LOCN_ID = ch.PREV_LOCN_ID)
Order By 
    ch.LOCN_ID
/*  
   R e s u l t :
   LOCN_ID PREV_LOCN_ID LOCN_ID_FROM_LOCN_HDR   CASE_NBR CASE_NOTE              LOCN_BRCD LOCN_BRCD_FROM_LOCN_HDR
---------- ------------ --------------------- ---------- --------------------- ---------- -----------------------
         1          101                     1          1 Linked by ID                   1                      11 
         2          102                   102          2 Linked by previous ID        102                      12 
         3          103                     3          1 Linked by ID                   3                      13 
         4          104                     4          1 Linked by ID                   4                      14 
         5          105                   105          2 Linked by previous ID        105                      15
*/
```